# Multi-column form unevenly displayed

Tags: css, forms, list

I'm experimenting with ways to create a two-tiered multi-column form that looks balanced. My latest attempt involves enveloping each label/input in an `li` and having them float into place. The attempt is somewhat successful, but there is a dimension issue that I can't resolve. 
The form is 600px wide and I made the `li`s 280px which would put the two columns roughly centered in the form. However, the effect is lopsided; everything is way too much to the left. It's like there is a huge margin of about 150px on the right hand side of the form - only there isn't.

In analyzing it, I noticed that the `input`s are actually measuring at 175px. However, if I try to increase the width, it goes to a new line, so they are acting like they are 280px. But you will notice in the jsfiddle, the last `li` is extending to the full width - 600px. Therefore, it can't be a result of any `fieldset` formatting. Furthermore, if I change the `float` to 'right', the 150px fake-margin is still there. Firebug detects all margins and padding as normal.

I just don't get it. 
I've tried renaming, applying additional classes, changing order of the li, removing attributes and adding other ones, and changing styling protocols... but usually I just make things worse. I would give up on the `ol li` concept altogether if any of my other techniques came as close to providing the display I am looking for. 
What's causing that 150px right margin? And how do I get rid of it? 
I need to understand this as the second part of the form is supposed to have two and three columns. So if `li`s cannot provide consistent widths, I have to try something else.

Here is the link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9344a/)
[http://jsfiddle.net/9344a/] 
Thank you in advance. (I've tried to clean it up, but the CSS/HTML may be a little bit messy as a result of trying different combinations. Let me know if anything is still difficult to understand.)

Comment: Your problem is in header menu?

Comment: No, with the actual label/input elements. Just look at the top part of the form; you see how the first six input fields are aligned to the left? They are the problems.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. And although it helped some (meaning it does have some impact) there is still extra margin on the right. More importantly, if I remove the <br> I don't get the two columns any more with the label on top of the inputs. It ends up looking like the second half of the form which is what I'm trying to fix. Besides, <br>s should not be affecting the display this much, should they? It's just a line break.

Comment: if you remove extra margin from right then there is three columns and two rows structure.is it what you want to do?

Comment: No, for this section I want only two. That's why the inputs were 280px. Remember, the form is on 600px, so the inputs should already be stretched close to each end... yet they are not. If you measure them, they are actually only about 175px even though I specified 280px.

Comment: Oh, and remember... there aren't any margins on the right. It is set to 0. So there shouldn't be any spacing there whatsoever. (Look at the bottom <li>, the comments, see how it extends all the way to the end while the ones on top do not? That's my issue. And I think you are on the right track with the <br> being a culprit, I just don't know how it helps; I do need a separate line for the label and input, and the only way to get it is with a line break. )

Answer (score 0):

You can give

```
  fieldset.partOne 
  {
      text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: But center align whould not work on a floating element, is that not right? Even float:right doesn't work, and that should be a valid option. The fake-right margin still exists.

Comment: But class fieldset.partOne is not floating element.

Comment: My bad - I just tried your command without the period and it did work (?!?!) although I'm at a loss why. However, what I would have preferred is the labels on the left, and the inputs the actual 280px in width. I eliminated the margin, but I don't have my dimensions... any thoughts?

Comment: But your whole li element is 280px ,if you want to inputs 280px you have to make li width larger than 280px;

Comment: My li element is 280px because the form/fieldset is 600px, and I wanted two columns. So 280px + 280px gives me 560px + a little room for padding. Now maybe I'm not applying the dimensions to the correct element (although I've tried many variations) but it still doesn't explain why the width is stubbornly remaining around 175px when that was not specified anywhere. And 300px is the largest I can make the li, and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You can give me rough image what you want?

Comment: Here is a quick drawing of what I'm referring to. The image link: http://postimg.org/image/eafhoa5s3/

Comment: For that please give the label width:280px; and for input width:280px.if necessary you can increase the li element width also

Comment: ? But isn't that exactly what my css shows? A 280px width for the li, label/input? That's my biggest problem. I have a 280px width but for some reason the width is being shortened to 175px on display. See Line 120 on my CSS

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually a compounding of errors.

> First, the `input` size was incorrectly targeted through `li` when it should have been targeted directly. 
>      `Example: fieldset.partOne ol li { width:280px; padding:5px 0 }  WRONG!    fieldset.partOne ol li input    { width:280px; padding:5px 0 }   or simply  fieldset.partOne input  { width:280px; padding:5px 0 }`
>
> In addition, setting the width of the `ol li` to 100% (a misguided attempt to increase the size of the input) would obviously prevent the float. 
>   The margin issue is caused by `fieldset.partOne ol li { width:280px; padding:5px 0 }`. Removing this width eliminates the fake margin. Not quite certain why, but the lesson is `ol li` works slightly differently within forms, so be aware of that.
>
> My concept for this form was fairly odd, and I made several errors with both my HTML and CSS in trying to achieve the end result. So I went back to the beginning and rebuilt from scratch and was able to create a non-standard multi-column form that met my odd criteria, used only CSS, and worked across most browsers.
>
> The Stackoverflow posts were invaluable in addressing all the little quirks that I came across, so I thought I'd return the favour and provide a jsfiddle that may help other newbies identify what they want and possibly how to get there. 
>   I would have found something like this enormously helpful.

Issues addressed:

- Aligning two and three column forms with various sized input elements.
- {ol li} or {div}? {li} Not a good solution for non-standard formats. I had to use {li} for one section and {div} for another section to make the form work.
- {select} sizing inconsistent. It usually has to be larger than your {input}
- Keeping smaller {inputs} from floating into gaps.
- Aligning odd shaped {input} and {label} fields.
- Font sizes and styles reverting to browser default (reset not applying to HTML5?)

> A non-resolved issue is FF top-aligning {select} data. There are many posts regarding this issue, but I have not found a good solution as of yet (one that targets only FF and does not affect other browsers). This is not a priority for me, but if it is for you, lots of advice is available. Do a search.
>
> Here is link that displays the form and shows the code: http://jsfiddle.net/LAVJn/1/
>
> Remember that this is written by a newbie, and you will certainly find many ways to improve upon it. But it does work and may be a good place to start or at least refine any questions you may have.
>   I don't think I am breaking any protocols doing this, but please let me know if that is not the case.